# Multidimensional array in foreach

Tags: php, foreach

i want to do the foreach only if the content of `myformdata[languages1][]` is not empty (include zero)

I already try:

```
  foreach((!empty($form['languages1']) as $val){

and

if (!empty($form['languages1'][])) {
foreach($form['languages1'] as $val){
//do stuff
}
```

i don't have any success. At the moment with the code below the loop is made when the input of `myformdata[languages1][]` is `0`

**foreach**

```
foreach($form['languages1'] as $val){
//do stuff
}
```

thanks

Comment: The first foreach doesn't even make sense. You're saying BOOLEAN as $value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ( $form['languages1'] as $val )
{
  // If the value is empty, skip to the next.
  if ( empty($val) )
    continue;
}
```

Reference: http://ca.php.net/continue

Comment: Alternatively `if(!empty($val)){ //do stuff }`. Continue belongs here though.

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with type coersion

You probably want something like

```
if(!empty($form['languages1']) && $form['languages1'] !== 0)
```

So that PHP will match 0 as a number, and not as false.